# PerformanceProgressBar only displays one dot

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the PerformanceProgressBar from Silverlight toolkit on the (pseudo) splashpage. However, it only displays one moving dot. What is wrong?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ActiveSplash" Height="Auto" Width="480" Background="Pink" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">            
        <Image Name="SplashScreenImage" Source="/SplashScreenImage.jpg"></Image>
        <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Width="480" Height="Auto"                                            
                    IsIndeterminate="True" 
                    Foreground="Blue" 
                    Background="Blue"
                    Margin="0,104,0,0" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried setting HorizontalAlignment to stretch perhaps?

Comment: is it happening in the designer or when you run the app?

Comment: When I run the app. All dots show up in the designer.

Comment: have u gone through this http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why would the Foreground & Background be the exact same color? :)

Comment: Its working fine on my emulator. Are you handling the progressbar somewhere in the code behind where you may be setting `IsIndeterminate="False"` at some point?

Comment: It shouldn't be touched anywhere. On an emulator it seems to randomly display 1-2 dots. Weird. @Chris W: I was trying to figure out if the dots were being rendered with foreground or background color.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app doing a lot of processing while using the performance progress bar?
I've notices that the more you have in the UI thread, less points you see in the bar.

Try doing your processing in a background thread

Comment: Oh yeah. The processing load is why I needed a progress bar in the first place. Seems like this could be the probable cause.

Comment: You can use the global ProgressIndicator which doesn't run on UIThread

Comment: I'm using it on a splash page, so global PI doesn't look pretty enough :)